# Multiple async webclient calls in backgroundworker (Silverlight 4)

Tags: c#, silverlight, asynchronous

**Requirement**:

- A Silverlight client that loads a file from the user's computer.
- For each row in the file it needs to issue a GET to a url and either approve or reject the row based on the JSON validation message returned.
- When all rows have completed, show the user a summary of how many rows passed and how many failed.

I would have preferred doing this "synchronously" in the BackgroundWorker, but that breaks the SL async thinking.

My code currently passes the result from the OpenFileDialog to a BackgroundWorker which reads the file into a list of strongly typed objects (client side validation). I create a WebClient and call DownloadStringAsync multiple times as I loop over the lines. More often than not, the background worker completes and runs the completed event method long before the WebClient is completed. The UI thread can run as async as it wants, but I need to either wait with completing the backgroundworker thread until it is actually finished getting the data, or have some additional event handler that works when all (hundreds) of rows have been validated.

What is best practice when wanting to handle the last Completed event of X total events? Any use of auto reset events here that could help?

Comment: Is there a reason why you aren't just sending the whole file to the server then getting the full set of validation messages in one round-trip to the server?

Comment: @AnthonyWJones File size, row count and reporting progress to the users made us select this approach. We tested "full dump" first, but the process takes a while and reporting live back to the user was considered to be a better functional approach, if not technically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't need to go to a background thread for that, nor you need to use an `AutoResetEvent` here. After reading the file, count the number of lines (= number of requests you'll send) and store it in an instance variable; then fire all the `WebRequest.DownloadAsync` (or some other `WebClient` async call to download the data). On each callback for the async method, you'd `Interlock.Decrement` the instance variable, and when it reaches 0, you know that you have all the results and you can display the summary to the client.

Comment: I'm not sure that processing a file and setting 100s of outstanding web requests is something you would want to do on the UI thread.  In fact I'm not sure you would really want to have 100s of instances of WebClient each with an outstanding request which when complete will fire an event into the UI thread.

Answer (score 1):

You can choose between random response sequence (but parallel execution)
 or ordered response but in sequential mode.
There is different cons and pros.

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Reactive.Linq;//Rx libriary
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

public partial class MainPage : UserControl
{
    private int count = 0;
    private int error = 0;

    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(StartParallel);
        //ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(StartSequential);
    }

    private void Update(Exception exception)
    {
        if (exception == null)
            Interlocked.Increment(ref count);
        else
            Interlocked.Increment(ref error);
        if ((count%100) == 0)
        {
            int count1 = count;
            Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => { textBox.Text = count1.ToString(); });
        }
    }

    private void StartSequential(object o)
    {
        //single instance of  WebClient
        WebClient wc = new WebClient();
        var observer = Observable.FromEventPattern<DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs>(wc, "DownloadStringCompleted")
            .Select(newResult => new {newResult.EventArgs.Error, newResult.EventArgs.Result});

        wc.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri("http://localhost:7123/SilverlightApplication2TestPage.aspx"));
        int i = 0;
        foreach (var nextValue in observer.Next())
        {
            if (i == 10000) break;
            wc.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri("http://localhost:7123/SilverlightApplication2TestPage.aspx"));
            Update(nextValue.Error);
        }
    }

    private void StartParallel(object o)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
        {
            //multiple instance of WebClient
            WebClient t = new WebClient();
            t.DownloadStringCompleted +=
                (x, nextValue) => Update(nextValue.Error);//order of result sequence is not guaranteed
            t.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri("http://localhost:7123/SilverlightApplication2TestPage.aspx"));
        }
    }
}
```